# Sparse matrix complains about negative index

Tags: matrix, runtime-error, sparse-matrix

I created a compressed sparse matrix, but while accessing to a positive index it complains that the index is negative:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
B= sparse.csc_matrix((110111213141516, 25))
B[11011121314,1]=99
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "criarS.py", line 28, in <module>
    B[11011121314,1]=99
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 511, in __setitem__
    self.check_format(full_check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 157, in check_format
    minor_name)
ValueError: row index values must be >= 0

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experiments with scipy 0.10.1, it would appear that `csc_matrix` indices have to fit in a C `long` (which on my platform is 32 bits wide).

If that assessment is correct, using a 64-bit build of Python might help get past this problem.